# Encode Python ASCII

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, encode

Olá, não estou conseguindo codificar corretamente a seguinte string no Python:

> algor\u00edtimo

Já tentei as seguintes alternativas:

```
u'algor\u00edtimo'.encode('utf-8')
'algor\u00edtimo'.decode('utf-8')
u'algor\u00edtimo'.encode('ascii')
u'algor\u00edtimo'.encode('ascii')
```

Comment: Bom, off-topic, mas respondendp..."algoritmo" não tem acento...é com "t" mudo, então não é proparoxítona.

Comment: Obrigado por comentar jsbueno.. mais esse foi apenas um exemplo de um crawler que estou fazendo para buscar títulos de post de um fórum. Abraço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seja isso o que você procura:

```py
plaintext = u'algor\u00edtimo'
encodedtext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
print (encodedtext)
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://ideone.com/edx907)</kbd>

Para codificar uma *string* para *ascii* podes fazer:

```
plaintext = u'algor\u00edtimo'
decodedtext = plaintext.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
print (decodedtext) # algortimo
```

O segundo parâmetro da função [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) faz com que prováveis erros sejam ignorados na conversão.

Para decodificar uma *string* pode-se usar a função [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) (ou [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode)):

```
plaintext = u'algor\u00edtimo'

encodedtext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
decodedtext = encodedtext.decode('utf-8')

print (encodedtext)      # algorítimo
print repr(decodedtext)  # u'algor\xedtimo'
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://ideone.com/xHM1Or)</kbd>

Isso é aplicável ao Python 2, para 3 há algumas diferenças, para mais informações consulte [**Unicode HOWTO**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). Veja também os [**padrões de codificação**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Se for possível especificar melhor em qual parte você está tendo dificuldades fica melhor para resolver o problema.